# explanation of d3.js transform and translate functions

Tags: d3.js

Can somebody explain what transform and translate are doing here:

```
d3.transform(d3.select(tick[0]).attr('transform')).translate[1];
```

The tick in the above is from an xaxis and its value might be `translate(0,280)`.

So I can see that I am picking out the second value of the translate function but why do I need to wrap all this in `d3.transform`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`d3.transform` is a helper function. Since there are many transformations available eg. `translate`, `rotate`, `scale` and all of its value goes inside same value field it is difficult to extract a single transformation.

```
<circle cx="10" cy="20" r="15" transform="translate(0,100)scale(2, 2)rotate(180)"></circle>
```

But if you wrap the selected objects transform attribute with `d3.transform` then you can access the individual components with the `d3.transform()` functions methods.

eg.

```
var c = d3.select('circle');

var tx = d3.transform(c.attr('transform')).translate 

var scale = d3.transform(c.attr('transform')).scale

var rotate = d3.transform(c.attr('transform')).rotate
```

Hope this is helpful.